# Assert String Upper is Called

Tags: python, pytest

How do I write a test to validate if a string manipulation was called or not? In this specific situation I'm trying to test that upper was called at least once. Since this is a python built in method it's a little different and I can't wrap my head around it.

```
# my function that returns an uppercase string example
def my_upper(str_to_upper: str) -> str:
   return str(str_to_upper).upper()

# my test that should determine that .upper() was called
def test_my_upper():
   # i assume I need some kind of mock here?
   my_upper('a')
   assert upper.call_count == 1
```

Update: I need to know if the core implementation of a very large product has changed. If I implement string manipulation and another dev comes in and changes how it works I want tests to immediately let me know so I can verify the implementation they added works or not.

Another update: here's what I've tried. It's complaining it can't find library 'str'.

```
from mock import patch


@patch("str.upper")
def test_my_upper(mock_upper):
   my_upper('a')
   assert mock_upper.call_count == 1
```

Comment: Normally, testing only cares about the results, not the implementation details.  `assert my_upper("foo") == "FOO"` tests that the function is doing what it's intended to; why should anyone care about how it accomplishes that?

Comment: Please avoid overwriting python keywords like `input` as this is a builtin to get user input from the terminal.

Comment: Updated my example based on ya'lls feedback.

Comment: Based on the code provided, it's not clear what `upper.call_count` is supposed to be. The `upper()` method of the `str` class doesn't have a `call_count` attribute, and `upper.call_count` wouldn't be the way to access it if it did.

Comment: I have made some more edits based on your feedback. My apologies for the bad example I provided.

Comment: I think `@patch` might only work on importable objects, not directly on built-in types. Maybe importing `builtins` and using `builtins.str.lower` instead might work.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the main question: you can use pytest spy
Reference: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/

```py
def test_spy_method(mocker):
    spy = mocker.spy(str, 'upper')

    spy.assert_has_called_once(21) # more advanced method could be used such as the ones with count
```

Answer the Update: It depends entirely of the implemented tests, if you have a plenty of ones which tests each of one the behaviors from it you MIGHT get a change. But if the change do something that keeps the tests results maybe tests will continue to work. Nitpick, tests isn't for this kind of matter, but to check the good behavior of a piece of software Thus, if the code changes and regression tests continue work as expected within the threshold coverage that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer for the another Update: Indeed, `str` isn't an imported object, at least not that you are used to be. And for what I've understood from the question you want to know about calls from a given method from `str`, this use cases fits perfectly by spy. Another point, is that you don't need the create a wrapper for a method to get something from test, actually the code should "live" a part from tests.

Comment: I like this and will look into it more. However, I'm not able to implement to achieve my goal. Getting this exception: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'